# Serving responsive images: how to use `grid` + `minmax` + `sizes` attribute?

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, css-grid

### Goal

optimize performance of a static site by serving the user the smallest image for their viewport.

not doing any art direction right now, but considering it for the future.

### Situation

a bunch of image-cards in a responsive grid

### Problem

how to set a reasonably effective `sizes` attribute for the `<img>` or `<picture`> element (meaning: how to estimate the image size up front) if I’m using `grid-template-columns(auto-fit, minmax(15rem, 1fr)`

### Thoughts

- guess: the sanest (best ratio of effort:effect) solution would be to ditch minmax and manage the layout via breakpoints instead of `minmax`. then set these breakpoints for the size attribute
- alternative?: keep `minmax` and use the devtools and figure out at what screensize the number of columns changes
- have been using the `<picture>` element while hacking away at this but I'm guessing an `<img>` would do?

---

Thanks for any input!

---

I've tried the "alternative?" and checked the network tab to see which image was being served. It was always the biggest one. Mind you, this was my last session before calling it a weekend.